# getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not be found while working with tesseract in windows

Tags: java, eclipse, tesseract

when i am trying to execute tess4j in eclipse in my windows 7 machine, i am getting the below error.

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not be found.

```
at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method) ~[jna.jar:4.2.1 (b0)]
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:263) ~[jna.jar:4.2.1 (b0)]
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:403) ~[jna.jar:4.2.1 (b0)]
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:147) ~[jna.jar:4.2.1 (b0)]
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:502) ~[jna.jar:4.2.1 (b0)]
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:481) ~[jna.jar:4.2.1 (b0)]
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.getTessAPIInstance(Unknown Source) ~[tess4j-3.0.jar:na]
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(Unknown Source) ~[tess4j-3.0.jar:na]
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Unknown Source) ~[tess4j-3.0.jar:na]
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source) ~[tess4j-3.0.jar:na]
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source) ~[tess4j-3.0.jar:na]
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source) ~[tess4j-3.0.jar:na]
at ocr.OCRController.handleFileUpload(OCRController.java:109) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
```

i am using **tess4j3.4.2 jar, os 64-bit, jdk-1.8: 64bit, eclipse neon2:64-bit**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also having the same specification as you.

Eclipse : 64bit

JDK 1.8 :64bit

OS :64bit

jar Tess4j :3.4.2 version

Check in your installed programs (Control Panel->Programs->Programs and Features) for

microsoft visual c++ 2015 redistributable  x64 is avalable or not.

If not then download it from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145) and install it.

Then try your app running again. It worked for me